# I cannot seed data from json file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am new to programming with asp.net core mvc. We are required to make a database and seed data from json file. Unfortunately I cannot seed the data from my json file and I can see that the Db is created with tables but no data in them. I am confused with older version where people use startup.cs and I dont know if my project need that or not. I will paste my project and i hope i get some solutions for it. Id appreciate any help. thanks

this is my program.cs

```
using Cenimas.Data;
using Cenimas.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Cenimas
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<CenimasContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
            builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IMailServices, NullMailServices>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<Seeder>();
            var app = builder.Build();
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            //app.MapRazorPages();
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            if (args.Length > 0 && args[0].ToLower() == "/seed")
            {
                SeedData(app);
            }
            app.Run();
            void SeedData(IHost app)
            {
                var scopedFactory = app.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
                using (var scope = scopedFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var seeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Seeder>();
                    seeder.Seed();
                }
            }


    }

        
    }
}
```

and this is my Seeder.cs

```
using Cenimas.Data.Entities;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Cenimas.Data
{
    public class Seeder
    {
        //private readonly CenimasContext context;

        //public Seeder(CenimasContext context)
        //{
        //    this.context = context;
        //}

        //public void Seed()
        //{
            //using (var contex = new CenimasContext(
            //    ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService.DbContextOption<CenimasContext>()))
            //{

            //}


            //if(!context.Products.Any())
            //{
            //    //var filePath = Path.Combine(hosting.ContentRootPath, "Data/art.json");
            //    //var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            //    //var products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Product>>(json);

            //    var order = new List<OrderItem>()
            //    {
            //        new OrderItem()
            //        {
            //            Product = products.First(),
            //            Quantity = 5,
            //            UnitPrice = products.First().Price
            //        }
            //    };

            //    context.Products.AddRange((IEnumerable<Product>)order);
            //    context.SaveChanges();
            //}
        //}


        private readonly CenimasContext ctx;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment hosting;

        public Seeder(CenimasContext ctx, IWebHostEnvironment hosting)
        {
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.hosting = hosting;
        }
        public void Seed()
        {
            ctx.Database.EnsureCreated(); //look at Db and see if its created
            if (!ctx.Movies.Any()) //if DB is not created
            {
                //create a path to our data that will be seeded in our database (in vid 01,04,15)
                var filePath = Path.Combine(hosting.ContentRootPath, "Data/MoviesList.json");
                var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                var movies = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Movies>>(json);

                //ctx.Movies.AddRange(movies);

                //var order = ctx.Orders.Where(o => o.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();    //crreating loop
                //if (order != null)
                //{
                //    order.Items = new List<OrderItem>()
                //    {
                //        new OrderItem()
                //        {
                //            Product = products.First(),
                //            Quantity = 5,
                //            UnitPrice = products.First().Price
                //        }
                //    };
                //}
                //ctx.Orders.Add(order);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }


            //}
        }
    }
}
```

CenimaContext.se

```
using Cenimas.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Cenimas.Data
{

    public class CenimasContext : DbContext
    {
        //private readonly IConfiguration config;
        private readonly IConfiguration appsettings;

        //public CenimasContext(IConfiguration config)
        //{
        //    this.config = config;
        //}
        public CenimasContext(IConfiguration appsettings)
        {
            this.appsettings = appsettings;
        }


        public DbSet<Movies> Movies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) // to connect our database
        {
            //var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            //    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("config").Build();
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(appsettings.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }
        //protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) // to show our data in tables
        //{
        //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        //        .HasData(new Order() // then we create migration to it (SeedData)
        //        {
        //            Id = 1,
        //            OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
        //            OrderNumber = "12345"
        //        });
        //}
    }
    
}
```

Movies.cs

```
namespace Cenimas.Data.Entities
{
    public class Movies
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Runtime { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Awards { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and a sample of json file MoviesList.json

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "Year": "2009",
    "Runtime": "162 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
    "Language": "English, Spanish",
    "Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations."

  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Title": "I Am Legend",
    "Year": "2007",
    "Released": "14 Dec 2007",
    "Genre": "Drama, Horror, Sci-Fi",
    "Awards": "9 wins & 21 nominations."
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Title": "300",
    "Year": "2006",
    "Released": "09 Mar 2007",
    "Genre": "Action, Drama, Fantasy",
    "Awards": "16 wins & 42 nominations."
  }
]
```

Comment: are there any exceptions? can you reach all the parts of your code while debugging while having an attached ide? can the code read the file? is the dbcontext save method called successfully? There is a lot of debugging you can do on your end to narrow down the actual problem. Then you can focus on the problem instead of on a broad symptom.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand the problem wihout debugging, but I think it might be because of **Deserializing**.

I would prefer to use **IOptions pattern** while converting JSON to C#. Check your JSON file carefully and then implement this if you like.

This is how you can implement it --> [enter link description here](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/)

You can use this link to understand using with arrays --> [IOptions Pattern with Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726171/asp-net-core-ioptions-with-a-list)

For console apps --> [IOptions for console apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837121/cannot-use-ioptions-in-console-app-net-core)

If the problem is because of this. It may help...

Comment: This is using startup.cs file but in my case I am not using it, and this is my problem i dont understand if I should use it or not?

Comment: I just wanted to give you an idea, this might help to implement.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837121/cannot-use-ioptions-in-console-app-net-core